# Flutter can't catch errors

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app I can't get the try/catch part to work properly.

```
Future<void> getTime() async {
    try {
        Response response = await get(Uri.parse('https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/worldtime?city=$location'),
                                      // provoke an error
                                      headers: {'Api_Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
        );  

        Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        time = "${data['hour']}h - ${data['minute']}m - ${data['second']}s";
    }   
    catch (e) {
        print('caught error: $e');
        time = 'could not get time data';
    }   
}
```

It looks like the catch section is not reached.
Any idea ?

Comment: are you getting any error maybe the request is successfully completed.

Comment: Check response.statusCode for errors.

Comment: @MunsifAli Yes I'm getting an error. I modified my request intentionally.

Comment: write throw Exception(); at the start of the try block and check if you are going to catch block or not

Comment: @MunsifAli Yes the catch block is reached when `throw Exception();` is at the start of the try block.

Comment: so there wouldn't be any Exception then i think

Comment: As currently shown, there is no exception. `http.get` returns a status code of 400 but does not throw an exception. the `time` variable ends up with `nullh - nullm - nulls` in it. If you corrupt the hostname in the URL, then you get an exception `SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'api.api-ninjas.con'` which is caught

Comment: @RichardHeap Correct. But where should I put the `throw Exception()` in my code ?

Comment: Which `throw Exception()`? Do you mean `if (response.statusCode != 200) throw Exception();` ? That seems kind of pointless - why not handle the error rather than throwing it?

Answer (score -3):

I guess the issue here is that try-catch blocks do not play well with async operations, in order to be able to catch errors in that context please refer to runZonedGuarded, it will encapsulate all method calls and listen to any exception thrown + handle them in a way just like catch does